# Calculate max-value from two time-stamps and assign it to each row in query results

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=c762382c40f8b0f321e6c2b9891c0a91)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    time_stamp DATE,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    plan_week VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO operations
(time_stamp, product, plan_week, quantity
)
VALUES 
("2020-01-01", "Product_A", "CW01", "100"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_B", "CW01", "300"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_C", "CW01", "200"),

("2020-03-15", "Product_A", "CW01", "100"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_B", "CW02", "400"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_C", "CW02", "150"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_D", "CW01", "170");
```

**Expected Results:**

```
time_stamp  |   product     |   plan_week   |    quantity    |   max_quantity
------------|---------------|---------------|----------------|------------------
2020-01-01  |   Product_A   |      CW01     |       100      |      100
2020-03-15  |   Product_A   |      CW01     |       100      |      100
            |               |               |                |
2020-01-01  |   Product_B   |      CW01     |       300      |      400
2020-03-15  |   Product_B   |      CW02     |       400      |      400
            |               |               |                |
2020-01-01  |   Product_C   |      CW01     |       200      |      200
2020-03-15  |   Product_C   |      CW02     |       150      |      200
            |               |               |                |
2020-03-15  |   Product_D   |      CW01     |       170      |      170
```

---

In the above result all `products` for each `time_stamp` are listed. 
In the last column I want to display the `max_quantity` from the two `time_stamps` for each `product` and assign it to **each row** in the result.

Therefore, I tried to go with this query but could not make it work:

```
SELECT
time_stamp,
product,
plan_week,
quantity,
(CASE WHEN MAX(quantity) over (partition by time_stamp, product)
THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS max_quantity
from operations
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2,1;
```

What do I need to change to get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below one - **[DEMO Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f006c6c1902905ab7788f8f1815c2004)**

```
SELECT time_stamp,product,plan_week,quantity,
       max(quantity) over(partition by product order by null) as max_quantity
from operations
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1c631e3ce94972f4f7bb5cf921fa6d0f

Answer (score 1):

Use `MAX` here as an analytic function:

```
SELECT time_stamp, product, plan_week, quantity,
       MAX(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY product) AS max_quantity
FROM operations
ORDER BY product, time_stamp;
```